# Modify google calendar input form

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps-script-addon

Because of personal purpose, I wanna modify the event input form (the form showing when clicking ***add new event*** on Google Calendar). Specifically, I wanna add some fields to this form. Can we do this? If we can, can you suggest what we should use to do this?

Many thanks for supporting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly change that form, but you could create a [Calendar add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/calendar). As it's stated in the documentation:

```
 G Suite add-ons are built using Apps Script, and their interfaces defined using the Apps Script Card service.
```

You will be able to create the custom interface you desire using [Card service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service) and use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to create the custom process you want.

[Building Google Calendar interfaces](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/calendar/building-calendar-interfaces) has more details about how you could build your interface and [Calendar actions](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/calendar/calendar-actions) has some examples of how you could handle the actions after clicking a button in your custom interface.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your details answer @alberto . I had take a look on google apps script before and this is useful for my case. But there are some confuse with this, my customer want to click to calendar to see the additional information on calendar form and i know this is impossible.So, is there a way to click on an on calendar and the add-on will also show the details which contain the addition on the custom interface? Like what i saw on [Gsuite](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-triggers) , the add-on will be trigger base on some special events

Comment: [Widgets](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/widgets) have several examples of what you could build and the [Calendar event object](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#calendar_event_object) shows what data you could handle. If you don't find there what you desire, then it's not possible to do what you want to do.